# How to query multiple MongoDB collections and NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have three collections in MongoDB.

In `Drug` JSON, using MEDID get its respective CMIDs from `Composition` JSON. Using that CMIDs get its respective *chemical Names* from the `Chemicals` JSON, then stores in one array with their `medid`, `cmid` and its `name`.

I'm using NodeJS. Please help me, thanks in advance.

## DRUG collection

```
{ 
   "MEDID":"AAA001-01",
   "BRANDNAME":"TASULIN D",
   "MEDTYPECODE":"CAP",
   "DOSE":"",
   "DOSEUNIT":"",
   "CHEMICAL1":"TAMSULSIN HYDROCHLORIDE",
   "CHEMICAL2":"DUTASTERIDE",
   "CHEMICAL3":"",
   "CHEMICAL4":"",
   "CHEMICAL5":"",
   "CHEMICAL6":"",
   "CHEMICAL7":"",
   "CHEMICAL8":"",
   "CHEMICAL9":"",
   "CHEMICAL10":"",
   "CHEMICAL11":"",
   "SPECIALITY":"GEN",
   "MANUFACTURER":"IPCA",
   "MFTID":"xyz123"
}
```

## Compostion Collection

```
{"MEDID":"AAA001-01","CMID":"ABC001"},
{"MEDID":"AAA001-01","CMID":"ABC002"}
```

## Chemical Collection

```
{"CMID":"ABC001","Name":"TAMSULSIN HYDROCHLORIDE"},
{"CMID":"ABC002","Name":"DUTASTERIDE"},
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a question here. What are you asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.drug.aggregate([
   {
     $lookup:
       {
         from: "composition",
         localField: "medid",
         foreignField: "medid",
         as: "composition"
       }
  },
    $lookup:
       {
         from: "chemical",
         localField: "composition.cmid",
         foreignField: "cmid",
         as: "chemical"
       }
   },
    $group: {
        _id: "$medid",
        cmid: { $first: "$composition.cmid" },
        name: { $first: "$chemical.name" }
]);
```

Comment: You mean `drug`, not `orders`.